# SQL Server Management Studio 2016: How to disable auto-capitalization of keywords

Tags: syntax, ssms

There was recently an update to SQL Server 2016 where keywords are automatically capitalized. While this is certainly convenient, I enjoy the freedom to capitalize words as I please (i.e. I don't always want keywords capitalized). Does anyone know how to disable this?

Comment: SQL Server does not "capitalize" anything. Are you referring to "SQL Server **Management Studio**"?

Comment: Yes. Thank you I've edited the title

Answer (score 2):

You can change the case you prefer to upper or lower under Tools / Options / Text Editor / Transact-SQL / IntelliSense

Comment: I tried that and it didn't do anything for the keywords. Also didn't seem to have any effect on function names :(

Answer (score 0):

if the build is not working for you,try going back to an earlier one

(uninstall the last update)